# Implementing Ant Colony Optimization on OSPF Protocol

Tags: routing

Since then, OSPF protocol uses Dijkstra's Algorithm for generating routing tables and the like. Is it possible to apply ACO and how would you do it? Thanks.
[Edited; added a comment below]

Comment: I have thought of modifying the OSPF's algo which is Dijkstra by replacing it with ACO or it can be Dijkstra with ACO. I will be conducting a comparison study for my undergraduate research project. Performance benchmarks and experiments will be conducted too. Thanks!

Comment: Questions about "_education, certification, or homework_" are specifically off-topic. You can learn how to ask good questions, and which topics are allowed in the [help]. Basically, Network Engineering is a site for network professionals to ask and answer questions about professional networks. You should edit your question to fit the rules.

Answer (score 6):

ACO and SPF (Dijkstra) would seem to be mutually exclusive.  You could in theory create a routing protocol based on ACO, but it would be something other than OSPF.  You could call it Protocol for Incremental Calculation of Networked Inter-node Clusters (PICNIC).